# Four different errors when using kubectl apply command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

My `docker-compose` file is as below:

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        build: .
        container_name: nginx
        ports:
            - '80:80'
```

And my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
```

I used `kompose konvert` and it created two files called `nginx-deployment.yml` and `nginx-service.yml` with the below contents.

`nginx-deployment.yml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: nginx
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:alpine
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

And `nginx-service.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "80"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

My `kustomization.yml`:

```
resources:
        - nginx-deployment.yml
        - nginx-service.yml
```

All files are in the same path `/home`.

I run these three commands but for each of them I got a different error:

1. `kubectl apply -f kustomization.yml`:

```
error: error validating "kustomization.yml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

2. `kubectl apply -k .`:

```
error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from 'nginx-deployment.yml': evalsymlink failure on '/home/nginx-deployment.yml' : lstat /home/nginx-deployment.yml: no such file or directory': evalsymlink failure on '/home/nginx-deployment.yml' : lstat /home/nginx-deployment.yml: no such file or directory
```

3. `kubectl apply -f kustomization.yml --validate=false`:

```
error: unable to decode "kustomization.yml": Object 'Kind' is missing in '{"resources":["nginx-deployment.yml","nginx-service.yml"]}'
```

4. `kubectl apply -k . --validate=false`:

```
error: accumulating resources: accumulation err='accumulating resources from 'nginx-deployment.yml': evalsymlink failure on '/home/nginx-deployment.yml' : lstat /home/nginx-deployment.yml: no such file or directory': evalsymlink failure on '/home/nginx-deployment.yml' : lstat /home/nginx-deployment.yml: no such file or directory
```

The `kubernetes` is a single node.

Why I'm getting these errors and how may I run my container in this environment?

Comment: You should not apply `kustomization.yaml`. You should use `-k` but it looks like you don't have the files in the same directory as you run the command?

Comment: @Jonas since then I figured out as @Faheem answered, that auto-generated file's extension is `yaml` but I point to `yml` file, so it says no such file or directory and that's pretty normal:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Kustomization.yml` file has two errors. The files generated by `kompose` have `.yaml` extensions but you are referring to `.yml` and you are missing the `kind` and `apiVersion` lines.

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - nginx-deployment.yaml
  - nginx-service.yaml
```

```sh
kubectl apply -k .
```

Comment: thanks, that was a point I did not notice regarding extension since I did not run `ls` command:)